# What is the meaning of letter 'c' in tblastn results before genomic sequence position?

Tags: blast

An example of a result. So far I have been unable to find the answer on my own.

">CP000000.0:c2005000-2006000 Escherichia coli strain XYZ chromosome

ATG..."

Comment: Please provide more details. Without context this could mean anything or nothing.

Comment: What more context should I give? I have the amino acid sequence of a protein and I want to find its genomic sequence in all available strains of a certain bacterium. I have tblastn hit results in .txt format. As I understand  after the accession number there is a colon and after it numbers signifying genomic position of hit sequence. In some cases, however, after the colon there is the letter 'c' and I have no clue what that means.

Comment: The `c` is from the database itself, so one would need to know exactly WHAT you're blasting against.